# Why does my await pool.query(query) not find data that exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-postgres

This is my schema (we want to focus on Dms):

```
-- USERS TABLE --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users;
CREATE TABLE Users(
   ident VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
   email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   firstName VARCHAR(32),
   lastName VARCHAR(32),
   accRole VARCHAR(32),
   active BOOLEAN,
   ua jsonb,
   UNIQUE (email)
);

-- WORKSPACES TABLE --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Workspaces;
CREATE TABLE Workspaces(
    workspacename VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY
);

-- CHANNELS TABLE --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Channels;
CREATE TABLE Channels(
    workspacename VARCHAR(32),
    channelname VARCHAR(16),
    chatlog jsonb,
    PRIMARY KEY (workspacename, channelname),
    FOREIGN KEY (workspacename) REFERENCES Workspaces(workspacename)
);

-- Dms table --
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Dms;
CREATE TABLE Dms(
    ident VARCHAR(32),
    identWith VARCHAR(32),
    workspacename VARCHAR(32),
    chatlog jsonb,
    PRIMARY KEY(ident, identWith, workspacename),
    FOREIGN KEY (ident) REFERENCES  Users(ident),
    FOREIGN KEY (identWith) REFERENCES  Users(ident),
    FOREIGN KEY (workspacename) REFERENCES Workspaces(workspacename)
);

DELETE FROM Users;
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('1', 'jc@ucsc.edu', 'Jack', 'Cooper', 'admin', NULL, '{"name":"Jack Cooper","password":"$2a$10$8y4LYm7f0qMnouiNMlg6puBNiy1siZi3bUEu5FKorTo8IPVxmOJYG","email":"jc@ucsc.edu", "role":"admin", "workspaces":["CSE 183 Summer 2021", "CSE 130"]}');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('2', 'ep@ucsc.edu', 'Emmanuel', 'Pena', 'admin', NULL, '{"name":"Emmanuel Pena", "password":"$2a$10$5TLsDwQXboHiXzTLSeZ01.5pjT76T3SQhyhulsSDST9fnoP.BT5x2", "email":"ep@ucsc.edu", "role": "admin", "workspaces":["CSE 183 Summer 2021", "CSE 130"]}');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('3', 'slug@ucsc.edu', 'Sammy', 'Slug', 'member', NULL, '{"name":"Sammy Slug","password":"$2a$10$FwbnonhdgakcpqlWpowVKudAy9Gdtu3LT45TDCux.WS5THA5Bxisi","email":"slug@ucsc.edu","role":"member", "workspaces":["CSE 183 Summer 2021", "Investors"]}');
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('4', 'turing@ucsc.edu', 'Alan', 'Turing', 'member', NULL, '{"name":"Alan Turing", "password":"$2a$10$mLMIMS9KAKfQKWJsgc3rbuwoiY.kWNKEGxv054OHhlVEPTzCQ8sfq", "email":"turing@ucsc.edu", "role":"member", "workspaces":["CSE 183 Summer 2021", "Investors"]}');

-- Workspaces TABLE --
DELETE FROM Workspaces;
INSERT INTO Workspaces(workspacename) VALUES ('CSE 183 Summer 2021');
INSERT INTO Workspaces(workspacename) VALUES ('CSE 130');
INSERT INTO Workspaces(workspacename) VALUES ('Investors');

-- Dms ident1 POPULATION --
DELETE FROM Dms;     -- missing names inserts NULL in their table column --
INSERT INTO Dms(ident, identWith, workspacename, chatlog) VALUES ('1', '2', 'CSE 183 Summer 2021', '[{"senderID":2, "from":"Emmanuel Pena", "date":"2021-07-20T07:15:23Z", "content":"How is the hw going?"}, {"senderID":1, "from":"Jack Cooper", "date":"2021-07-20T07:29:28Z", "content":"Not bad. And for you?"}, {"senderID":2, "from":"Emmanuel Pena", "date":"2021-07-20T07:33:25Z", "content":"Same here."}]');
INSERT INTO Dms(ident, identWith, workspacename, chatlog) VALUES ('1', '3', 'CSE 183 Summer 2021', '[{"senderID":1, "from":"Jack Cooper", "date":"2021-07-20T06:14:22Z", "content":"Hey"}, {"senderID":3, "from":"Sammy Slug", "date":"2021-07-20T06:23:28Z", "content":"What is up?"}]');
INSERT INTO Dms(ident, identWith, workspacename, chatlog) VALUES ('1', '4', 'CSE 183 Summer 2021', '[{"senderID":4, "from":"Alan Turing", "date":"2021-07-21T01:12:29Z", "content":"You needed help with basic?"}, {"senderID":1, "from":"Jack Cooper", "date":"2021-07-21T01:15:22Z", "content":"Yes! Thanks for dming."}]');
INSERT INTO Dms(ident, identWith, workspacename, chatlog) VALUES ('1', '2', 'CSE 130', '[{"senderID":1, "from":"Jack Cooper", "date":"2021-07-20T07:19:13Z", "content":"We have this class too"}, {"senderID":2, "from":"Emmanuel Pena", "date":"2021-07-20T07:25:32Z", "content":"Lol yup"}]');
-- Dms ident2 POPULATION --
INSERT INTO Dms(ident, identWith, workspacename, chatlog) VALUES ('2', '1', 'CSE 183 Summer 2021', '[{"senderID":2, "from":"Emmanuel Pena", "date":"2021-07-20T07:15:23Z", "content":"How is the hw going?"}, {"senderID":1, "from":"Jack Cooper", "date":"2021-07-20T07:29:28Z", "content":"Not bad. And for you?"}, {"senderID":2, "from":"Emmanuel Pena", "date":"2021-07-20T07:33:25Z", "content":"Same here."}]');
INSERT INTO Dms(ident, identWith, workspacename, chatlog) VALUES ('2', '3', 'CSE 183 Summer 2021', '[{"senderID":3, "from":"Sammy Slug", "date":"2021-07-21T02:12:29Z", "content":"Hello!"}]');
INSERT INTO Dms(ident, identWith, workspacename, chatlog) VALUES ('2', '1', 'CSE 130', '[{"senderID":1, "from":"Jack Cooper", "date":"2021-07-20T07:19:13Z", "content":"We have this class too"}, {"senderID":2, "from":"Emmanuel Pena", "date":"2021-07-20T07:25:32Z", "content":"Lol yup"}]');

DELETE FROM Channels;
INSERT INTO Channels(workspacename, channelname, chatlog) VALUES ('CSE 183 Summer 2021', '# Assignment 1', '[{"senderID":2, "from":"Emmanuel Pena", "date":"2021-07-18T07:17:54Z", "content":"Hello there"}, {"senderID":1, "from":"Jack Cooper", "date":"2021-07-18T07:55:51Z", "content":"Hey Emmanuel"}, {"senderID":4, "from":"Alan Turing", "date":"2021-07-19T06:12:54Z", "content":"Any1 struggling?"}]');
```

I want to get the dms between two user idents. Now my user.js has:

```
exports.getDmsWithUser = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.query.ident;
  const ws = req.query.ws;
  const identWith = req.query.identWith;

  console.log('user.js) about to enter db.js');
  const dmsChat = await db.getDmsWithUser(id, ws, identWith);
  if (dmsChat === null) {
    console.log('user.js) returned null. no rows counted');
    res.status(404).send();
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(dmsChat);
  }
};
```

and my db.js has:

```
exports.getDmsWithUser = async (ident, ws, identWith) => {
  console.log('db.js) inside db.js');
  const select = 'SELECT chatlog FROM Dms WHERE ident LIKE $1 AND workspacename LIKE $2 AND identWith LIKE $3';

  const query = {
    text: select,
    values: [ident, ws, identWith],
  };

  console.log('console.logging query.values:');
  console.log(query.values);

  const {rows} = await pool.query(query);

  console.log('console.logging rows:');
  console.log(rows);
 
  console.log('db.js) ran query. Going to count rows now.. count will apear if > 0');
  if (rows.length > 0) {
    console.log('db.js) counted rows. going to return chatlog now');
    console.log('db.js) about to print row count..');
    console.log(rows.length);
    console.log('db.js) about to print row 0');
    console.log(rows[0]);
    console.log('db.js) about to print row 0.chatlog');
    console.log(rows[0].chatlog);
    return rows[0].chatlog;
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

It seems as if I enter 1 for ident, CSE 130 for ws, & 2 for identWith on Swagger UI, I should be returning the chatlog json from the FOURTH insert of data into the Dms table correct? However, the output I get on power shell is:

```
user.js) about to enter db.js
db.js) inside db.js
console.logging query.values:
[ '1', 'CSE 130', '2' ]
console.logging rows:
[]
db.js) ran query. Going to count rows now.. count will apear if > 0
user.js) returned null. no rows counted
```

and Swagger UI says 404 Error: Not Found (not even 404 ChatLog Not Found?):

[Swagger UI server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9YVW.png)

Pleeease any help would be greatly appreciated..
For some reason 'SELECT chatlog FROM Channels WHERE workspacename LIKE $1 AND channelname LIKE $2' for getting a channel's chatlog works though.., so it's hard to understand why it doesn't all of a sudden when I make use of the idents if my functions are pretty much the same in everything BUT the query stuff (use of idents/channelname).. what should I investigate next?

Comment: Can you log the `query.values` to ensure you've sent the right things?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`?

Comment: @Bergi. I just edited this with those console.logs, and as I thought, the values are indeed correct. So I know I have a correct query. And I do plan on changing the LIKE.

Comment: Hm, [appears to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=46fe23af768f2165ef8a86b0fd1f8d72)…

Comment: Yup that's why I'm confused as to why a blank [] is assigned to rows. All my other functions seem to be correctly updating my data and retrieving from my data